# Iframe access on elements

Tags: javascript, iframe, getelementbyid, javascript-injection

I use an Iframe with an external API, which I don't control. My goal is to add Javascript code in my Website, to change the style of a few elements in the Iframe. First I considered using

```
document.getElementById(iframeId).contentWindow.document.getElementById(elementId);
```

but I soon recognized that it will not be successful because I am getting security issues. I tested a bit and found out when I inspect the element in the Iframe, which I want to change, I am able to get the element simply by using:

```
document.getElementById(elementId);
```

I don't understand.  Why does this technique only work when I inspect the correct element first? And is there any way I can use this trick for my normal JS backend?

Comment: Developer Tools can access anything in the web page. But scripts can only access parts of the page from the same domain. If the iframe is in a different domain, the script can't access it directly.

Comment: Okay thank you. That's unfortunate for me but answer the question.